# MongoDB aggregate sum returns invalid result

Tags: node.js, mongodb, aggregation-framework

**This is MongoDB Tabe I am using when it tries to calculate the sum qty it returns the wrong result and I don't know why**

```
┌─────────┬───────────────┬───────┬─────────┬────────┐
│ (index) │     code      │  qty  │ product │ branch │
├─────────┼───────────────┼───────┼─────────┼────────┤
│    0    │ '114=>115-41' │ 0.34  │ '4009'  │  '1'   │
│    1    │ '114=>115-41' │ -0.02 │ '4009'  │  '1'   │
│    2    │ '114=>115-41' │ -0.06 │ '4009'  │  '1'   │
│    3    │ '114=>115-41' │ -0.12 │ '4009'  │  '1'   │
│    4    │ '114=>115-41' │ -0.14 │ '4009'  │  '1'   │
└─────────┴───────────────┴───────┴─────────┴────────┘
```

**The query:**

```
let AggreArray=[
    
    {
      $group:{
        _id: {
          code:"$code",
          product:"$product",
          branch:"$branch",
        },
       qty: {$sum: "$qty" },
      }
    }
]

db.coll.aggregate(AggreArray).toArray((err, result) => {
    console.log(result);
            
});
```

instead of returning `qty: 0` it returns

```
[
  {
    _id: {
      product: 5fec20bc26b1650017003f4a,
      code: '114=>115-41',
      branch: 5fec43f269cdbd300ccf9275
    },enter code here
    qty: 2.7755575615628914e-17, // expected 0
    
  }
]
```

instead of returning `qty: 0` it returns `Qty: 2.775575`.
and I don't know why plz help me I was trying to fix it all mayday and I cannot.

Comment: You need to refer to the field `product` using the `$` syntax in the `$group` stage.

Comment: it is still the same result

Comment: Can you tell why you are expecting a `0` (zero) value for the result `qty`?

Comment: becouse 0.34 - 0.02 -0.06 - 0.12 - 0.14 = 0. is't it

Comment: But, the result is not showing as `2.775575`. It is showing as `2.7755575615628914e-17`. In MongoDB, numbers by default are of type `double` and the arithmetic returns not an exact zero.

Comment: how can i get exact zero

Comment: can you please help me to ti exact zero

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In MongoDB all numbers are 64-bit floating-point double values, by default. The [NumberDecimal](https://docs.mongodb.com/v4.2/core/shell-types/#numberdecimal) type is used to explicitly specify 128-bit decimal-based floating-point values capable of emulating decimal rounding with *exact precision*. This data type can give you the desired result of `0`(zero).

That is, in your aggregation you need to convert the `qty` to a `NumberDecimal` type. This is a two step process - first the number is to be converted to a *string* type, and then to the `NumberDecimal` type (this is because the `NumberDecimal` constructor expects a string as its parameter).

So, your aggregation works with the following changes to return a result of `0` (zero):

```
db.coll.aggregate([     
{
  $match: { 
      product: ObjectId('5fec20bc26b1650017003f4a'),
      code: '114=>115-41',         
      branch: ObjectId('5fec43f269cdbd300ccf9275'),       
  }     
},
{ 
  $addFields: { qty: { $toDecimal: { $toString: "$qty" } } }
},
{
  $group:{
      _id: { code:"$code", product:"$product", branch:"$branch" },        
      qty:  { $sum: "$qty" },       
  }     
},
{ 
  $addFields: { qty: { $toDouble:  "$qty" } }
}
])
```

NOTE: In MongoDB NodeJS Driver, `NumberDecimal` is represented as [Decimal128](http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/3.6/api/Decimal128.html).